# To process payload inside script mediator in WSO2 EI/ESB

Tags: javascript, wso2, rhino, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am having payload like below. **I need to get that whole payload inside script mediator and perform slash removal operation for that payload**. I can't able to get full payload, gets only one json element inside script mediator. Can anyone please help me?

**RequestPayload:**

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><jsonObject xmlns
="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><jsonValue xmlns="">"{\"transactionId\":null,\"timestamp\":\"2020-04-28 14:21:01\",\"OpportunityId\":\"0065500000Fz6EdAAJ\",\"message\":\"Insert/
Update success\",\"Lead\":{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AvaJ8EAJ\"},\"Company\":\"N/A\",\"Email\":\"dunleavy2010@hotmail
.com\",\"Lead_Type__c\":\"Internet\",\"LeadSource\":\"LDV i-Motor - Get a Quote\",\"FirstName\":\"Brendan\",\"LastName\":\"Dunleavy\",\"Id\":\"00Q5500000AvaJ8EAJ\",\"MobilePhone\":
\"+61 449 819 834\"},\"errorCode\":\"200\",\"appraisalId\":null}"</jsonValue><jsonValue xmlns="">"{\"transactionId\":null,\"timestamp\":\"2020-04-28 14:21:01\",\"OpportunityId\":\"
0065500000Fz6EiAAJ\",\"message\":\"Insert/Update success\",\"Lead\":{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AvaJ3EAJ\"},\"Company\
":\"N/A\",\"Email\":\"steveross01@bigpond.com\",\"Lead_Type__c\":\"Internet\",\"LeadSource\":\"LDV Facebook - Book a Test Drive\",\"FirstName\":\"Stephen\",\"LastName\":\"Ross\",\"
Id\":\"00Q5500000AvaJ3EAJ\",\"MobilePhone\":\"+61 414 404 774\"},\"errorCode\":\"200\",\"appraisalId\":null}"</jsonValue><jsonValue xmlns="">"{\"transactionId\":null,\"timestamp\":
\"2020-04-28 14:21:04\",\"OpportunityId\":\"0065500000Fz6EnAAJ\",\"message\":\"Insert/Update success\",\"Lead\":{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v48.0/so
bjects/Lead/00Q5500000AvaJDEAZ\"},\"Company\":\"N/A\",\"Email\":\"jaxonstevens18@gmail.com\",\"Lead_Type__c\":\"Internet\",\"LeadSource\":\"LDV i-Motor - Get a Quote\",\"FirstName\
":\"Jaxon\",\"LastName\":\"Stevens\",\"Id\":\"00Q5500000AvaJDEAZ\",\"MobilePhone\":\"+61 423 927 100\"},\"errorCode\":\"200\",\"appraisalId\":null}"</jsonValue></jsonObject></soape
nv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Proxy Code:**

```
<proxy name="VBReadFromEmailBody" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<target>
    <inSequence>
                <iterate expression="//jsonArray/jsonElement" id="LDVid" sequential="true">
                    <target>
                        <sequence>
                            <!-- Each jsonElement is pushed to SalesForce  -->
                            <sequence description="VBEmail_LDVNonQualifiedLead_Sequence" key="VBEmail_LDVNonQualifiedLead_Sequence"/>
                        </sequence>
                    </target>
                </iterate>
                <property name="Aggregated_Responses" scope="default">
                    <jsonObject/>
                </property>
                <aggregate id="LDVid">
                    <completeCondition>
                        <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
                    </completeCondition>
                    <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="Aggregated_Responses" expression="$body/*[1]" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
                        <loopback/>
                    </onComplete>
                </aggregate>
     </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <log level="custom">
            <property name="======OUTSEQUENCE=======" value="CALLED"/>
        </log>
        <!-- Log to check aggregatedresponse  -->
        <log level="full"/>
                <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
                <iterate expression="//jsonValue" sequential="true">
                    <target>
                        <sequence>
                            <property expression="json-eval($)" name="jsonString" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                            <script language="js"><![CDATA[var log = mc.getServiceLog();        
var payload = mc.getProperty('jsonString').toString();log.info("script payload::::" + payload); payloadRemoveSlash = payload.replace('\\', '').replace('"{','{').replace('}"','}'); mc.setProperty('payloadRemoveSlash',payloadRemoveSlash);]]></script>
                        <log level="custom">
                          <property name=":: Body Inside payloadRemoveSlash::" expression="$ctx:payloadRemoveSlash"/>
                        </log>
                        <enrich>
            <source clone="true" type="inline">
                <test xmlns="">abc</test>
            </source>
            <target type="body"/>
        </enrich>
        <payloadFactory description="Form Salesforce Request" media-type="json">
            <format>$1</format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('payloadRemoveSlash')"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
                    <log level="custom">
                          <property name="After Enrich" expression="json-eval($.)"/>
                        </log>
                        </sequence>
                    </target>
                </iterate>
 </outSequence>
    <faultSequence>
        <log level="custom">
            <property description="ERROR_CODE" name="ERROR_CODE" scope="default" type="STRING" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
            <property description="ERROR_MESSAGE" name="ERROR_MESSAGE" scope="default" type="STRING" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')/>
        </log>

     </faultSequence>
</target>
```

**Wire Logs - 1:**

```
[2020-04-28 14:48:25,594] []  INFO - LogMediator LogText = Salesforce Request Uniqueidentifier:17132e6366d3d561,**, ======SF RequestPayload====== = {"getLead":{"Company":"N/A","Ema
    il":"dunleavy2010@hotmail.com","Lead_Type__c":"Internet","LeadSource":"LDV i-Motor - Get a Quote","FirstName":"Brendan","LastName":"Dunleavy","MobilePhone":"+61 449 819 834"},"getT
    rade":[]}
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,596] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "POST /services/apexrest/LeadIntegrationAPIHandler HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,596] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Authorization: Bearer  00D550000000fgk!AR0AQALfr1npMosFbJQ.zn17zoWY2WnRXuFTNtBCPnkmo_WaCG9uvQJ68D.l.5NPI
    dIg0AUsv0yHmucn8ikq6inf74ePBFu3[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,596] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,597] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q04
    8=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,599] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,600] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "ETag: "hicYA7eHlMWnqap7I2cx6HOrcNI/vfNEq8c2pcFW4FNGRTeNcH6yFic"[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,600] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,600] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,601] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Vary: Origin[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,601] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Vary: X-Origin[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,602] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Expires: Tue, 28 Apr 2020 09:18:05 GMT[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,602] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,602] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,603] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,603] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Host: vonbibra--vbdevmerge.my.salesforce.com[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,603] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,604] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,604] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,604] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "dd[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,605] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "{"getLead":{"Company":"N/A","Email":"dunleavy2010@hotmail.com","Lead_Type__c":"Internet","LeadSource":"L
    DV i-Motor - Get a Quote","FirstName":"Brendan","LastName":"Dunleavy","MobilePhone":"+61 449 819 834"},"getTrade":[]}[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,605] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "0[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:25,605] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,341] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,341] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "Date: Tue, 28 Apr 2020 09:18:20 GMT[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,341] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536002; includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,342] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only: pin-sha256="9n0izTnSRF+W4W4JTq51avSXkWhQB8duS2bxVLfzXsY="; pin-sha256="5kJv
    NEMw0KjrCAu7eXY5HZdvyCS13BbA0VJG1RSP91w="; pin-sha256="njN4rRG+22dNXAi+yb8e3UMypgzPUPHlv4+foULwl1g="; max-age=86400; includeSubDomains; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/hp
    kp-report/00D550000000fgkm";[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,342] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "Expect-CT: max-age=86400, report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/Expect-CT-report/00D550000000fgkm"[\
    r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,342] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,343] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,343] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "X-Robots-Tag: none[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,343] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,344] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "Set-Cookie: BrowserId=M-JoJIkxEeqAhF-kj0dI8Q; domain=.salesforce.com; path=/; expires=Wed, 28-Apr-2021 0
    9:18:20 GMT; Max-Age=31536000[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,344] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,344] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "Vary: Accept-Encoding[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,345] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,345] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,345] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "223[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:28,346] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> ""{\"transactionId\":null,\"timestamp\":\"2020-04-28 19:18:24\",\"OpportunityId\":\"0065500000Fz9foAAB\",
    \"message\":\"Insert/Update success\",\"Lead\":{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AvbtgEAB\"},\"Company\":\"N/A\",\"Email\":\
    "jaxonstevens18@gmail.com\",\"Lead_Type__c\":\"Internet\",\"LeadSource\":\"LDV i-Motor - Get a Quote\",\"FirstName\":\"Jaxon\",\"LastName\":\"Stevens\",\"Id\":\"00Q5500000AvbtgEAB\
    ",\"MobilePhone\":\"+61 423 927 100\"},\"errorCode\":\"200\",\"appraisalId\":null}""
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,084] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,084] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "0[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,084] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 >> "[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,631] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,632] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Date: Tue, 28 Apr 2020 09:18:26 GMT[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,632] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536002; includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,632] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only: pin-sha256="9n0izTnSRF+W4W4JTq51avSXkWhQB8duS2bxVLfzXsY="; pin-sha256="5kJv
    NEMw0KjrCAu7eXY5HZdvyCS13BbA0VJG1RSP91w="; pin-sha256="njN4rRG+22dNXAi+yb8e3UMypgzPUPHlv4+foULwl1g="; max-age=86400; includeSubDomains; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/hp
    kp-report/00D550000000fgkm";[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,633] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Expect-CT: max-age=86400, report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/Expect-CT-report/00D550000000fgkm"[\
    r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,634] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,634] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,634] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "X-Robots-Tag: none[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,634] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,635] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Set-Cookie: BrowserId=N0LRQokxEeqAhF-kj0dI8Q; domain=.salesforce.com; path=/; expires=Wed, 28-Apr-2021 0
    9:18:26 GMT; Max-Age=31536000[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,635] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,635] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Vary: Accept-Encoding[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,636] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,636] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,636] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "226[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,637] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> ""{\"transactionId\":null,\"timestamp\":\"2020-04-28 19:18:29\",\"OpportunityId\":\"0065500000Fz9fyAAB\",
    \"message\":\"Insert/Update success\",\"Lead\":{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AvbtlEAB\"},\"Company\":\"N/A\",\"Email\":\
    "dunleavy2010@hotmail.com\",\"Lead_Type__c\":\"Internet\",\"LeadSource\":\"LDV i-Motor - Get a Quote\",\"FirstName\":\"Brendan\",\"LastName\":\"Dunleavy\",\"Id\":\"00Q5500000AvbtlE
    AB\",\"MobilePhone\":\"+61 449 819 834\"},\"errorCode\":\"200\",\"appraisalId\":null}"[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,637] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "0[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,638] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "[\r][\n]"
    [2020-04-28 14:48:29,651] []  INFO - LogMediator ======OUTSEQUENCE======= = CALLED
```

**Wire Logs - 2: script related wirelogs**

```
[2020-04-28 14:48:29,653] []  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:14c06142-fccf-4a80-ba38-b8f040c992de, Direction: response, Envelope: <?xml vers
        ion='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><jsonObject xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><jsonValue
         xmlns="">"{\"transactionId\":null,\"timestamp\":\"2020-04-28 19:18:24\",\"OpportunityId\":\"0065500000Fz9ftAAB\",\"message\":\"Insert/Update success\",\"Lead\":{\"attributes\":{\"
        type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AvbtbEAB\"},\"Company\":\"N/A\",\"Email\":\"steveross01@bigpond.com\",\"Lead_Type__c\":\"Internet\",\"LeadSou
        rce\":\"LDV Facebook - Book a Test Drive\",\"FirstName\":\"Stephen\",\"LastName\":\"Ross\",\"Id\":\"00Q5500000AvbtbEAB\",\"MobilePhone\":\"+61 414 404 774\"},\"errorCode\":\"200\",
        \"appraisalId\":null}"</jsonValue><jsonValue xmlns="">"{\"transactionId\":null,\"timestamp\":\"2020-04-28 19:18:24\",\"OpportunityId\":\"0065500000Fz9foAAB\",\"message\":\"Insert/U
        pdate success\",\"Lead\":{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AvbtgEAB\"},\"Company\":\"N/A\",\"Email\":\"jaxonstevens18@gmail.
        com\",\"Lead_Type__c\":\"Internet\",\"LeadSource\":\"LDV i-Motor - Get a Quote\",\"FirstName\":\"Jaxon\",\"LastName\":\"Stevens\",\"Id\":\"00Q5500000AvbtgEAB\",\"MobilePhone\":\"+6
        1 423 927 100\"},\"errorCode\":\"200\",\"appraisalId\":null}"</jsonValue><jsonValue xmlns="">"{\"transactionId\":null,\"timestamp\":\"2020-04-28 19:18:29\",\"OpportunityId\":\"0065
        500000Fz9fyAAB\",\"message\":\"Insert/Update success\",\"Lead\":{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AvbtlEAB\"},\"Company\":\"
        N/A\",\"Email\":\"dunleavy2010@hotmail.com\",\"Lead_Type__c\":\"Internet\",\"LeadSource\":\"LDV i-Motor - Get a Quote\",\"FirstName\":\"Brendan\",\"LastName\":\"Dunleavy\",\"Id\":\
        "00Q5500000AvbtlEAB\",\"MobilePhone\":\"+61 449 819 834\"},\"errorCode\":\"200\",\"appraisalId\":null}"</jsonValue></jsonObject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
        [2020-04-28 14:48:29,658] []  INFO - LogMediator ====each payload==== = "{\"transactionId\":null,\"timestamp\":\"2020-04-28 19:18:24\",\"OpportunityId\":\"0065500000Fz9ftAAB\",\"me
        ssage\":\"Insert/Update success\",\"Lead\":{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AvbtbEAB\"},\"Company\":\"N/A\",\"Email\":\"ste
        veross01@bigpond.com\",\"Lead_Type__c\":\"Internet\",\"LeadSource\":\"LDV Facebook - Book a Test Drive\",\"FirstName\":\"Stephen\",\"LastName\":\"Ross\",\"Id\":\"00Q5500000AvbtbEAB
        \",\"MobilePhone\":\"+61 414 404 774\"},\"errorCode\":\"200\",\"appraisalId\":null}"
        [2020-04-28 14:48:29,665] []  INFO - CommonScriptMessageContext script payload::::{"transactionId":null,"timestamp":"2020-04-28 19:18:24","OpportunityId":"0065500000Fz9ftAAB","mess
        age":"Insert/Update success","Lead":{"attributes":{"type":"Lead","url":"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AvbtbEAB"},"Company":"N/A","Email":"steveross01@bigpond.com","L
        ead_Type__c":"Internet","LeadSource":"LDV Facebook - Book a Test Drive","FirstName":"Stephen","LastName":"Ross","Id":"00Q5500000AvbtbEAB","MobilePhone":"+61 414 404 774"},"errorCod
        e":"200","appraisalId":null}
        [2020-04-28 14:48:29,666] []  INFO - LogMediator ====each payload==== = "{\"transactionId\":null,\"timestamp\":\"2020-04-28 19:18:24\",\"OpportunityId\":\"0065500000Fz9ftAAB\",\"me
        ssage\":\"Insert/Update success\",\"Lead\":{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AvbtbEAB\"},\"Company\":\"N/A\",\"Email\":\"ste
        veross01@bigpond.com\",\"Lead_Type__c\":\"Internet\",\"LeadSource\":\"LDV Facebook - Book a Test Drive\",\"FirstName\":\"Stephen\",\"LastName\":\"Ross\",\"Id\":\"00Q5500000AvbtbEAB
        \",\"MobilePhone\":\"+61 414 404 774\"},\"errorCode\":\"200\",\"appraisalId\":null}"
        [2020-04-28 14:48:29,671] []  INFO - CommonScriptMessageContext script payload::::{"transactionId":null,"timestamp":"2020-04-28 19:18:24","OpportunityId":"0065500000Fz9ftAAB","mess
        age":"Insert/Update success","Lead":{"attributes":{"type":"Lead","url":"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AvbtbEAB"},"Company":"N/A","Email":"steveross01@bigpond.com","L
        ead_Type__c":"Internet","LeadSource":"LDV Facebook - Book a Test Drive","FirstName":"Stephen","LastName":"Ross","Id":"00Q5500000AvbtbEAB","MobilePhone":"+61 414 404 774"},"errorCod
        e":"200","appraisalId":null}
        [2020-04-28 14:48:29,672] []  INFO - LogMediator ====each payload==== = "{\"transactionId\":null,\"timestamp\":\"2020-04-28 19:18:24\",\"OpportunityId\":\"0065500000Fz9ftAAB\",\"me
        ssage\":\"Insert/Update success\",\"Lead\":{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AvbtbEAB\"},\"Company\":\"N/A\",\"Email\":\"ste
        veross01@bigpond.com\",\"Lead_Type__c\":\"Internet\",\"LeadSource\":\"LDV Facebook - Book a Test Drive\",\"FirstName\":\"Stephen\",\"LastName\":\"Ross\",\"Id\":\"00Q5500000AvbtbEAB
        \",\"MobilePhone\":\"+61 414 404 774\"},\"errorCode\":\"200\",\"appraisalId\":null}"
        [2020-04-28 14:48:29,678] []  INFO - CommonScriptMessageContext script payload::::{"transactionId":null,"timestamp":"2020-04-28 19:18:24","OpportunityId":"0065500000Fz9ftAAB","mess
        age":"Insert/Update success","Lead":{"attributes":{"type":"Lead","url":"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AvbtbEAB"},"Company":"N/A","Email":"steveross01@bigpond.com","L
        ead_Type__c":"Internet","LeadSource":"LDV Facebook - Book a Test Drive","FirstName":"Stephen","LastName":"Ross","Id":"00Q5500000AvbtbEAB","MobilePhone":"+61 414 404 774"},"errorCod
        e":"200","appraisalId":null}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for my problem. I used property expression as **"$body/*[1]"*** instead of **"json-eval($)"** inside iterator. first tried with json-eval($) which holds same json for each iteration ie script mediator log prints same payload for each iteration, later changing that into "$body/[1]" which generates different payload luckily.

```
         <iterate continueParent="true" expression="//jsonValue" sequential="true">
                        <target>
                            <sequence>
                                <log level="full"/>
                                <property expression="$body/*[1]" name="jsonString" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                                <script language="js"><![CDATA[var log = mc.getServiceLog();        
                                var payload = mc.getProperty('jsonString').toString(); 
                                payloadRemoveSlash = payload.replace('\\', '').replace('"{','{').replace('}"','}');
                                //payloadRemoveSlash = payload.replace("\\", "");
                                 mc.setProperty('payloadRemoveSlash',payloadRemoveSlash);
                                //log.info("payloadRemoveSlash:::" +payloadRemoveSlash)]]></script>
                                <enrich>
                                    <source clone="true" xpath="$ctx:payloadRemoveSlash"/>
                                    <target type="body"/>
                                </enrich>
                          </sequence>
                        </target>
                    </iterate>
```

Comment: I see the only difference between your answer and mine was using Iterate instead of ForEach. What other changes have you done? @justin

Answer (score 1):

As per the functionality of For-Each and Iterate mediators, the whole message will be split into parts based on the expression you provide. Hence only one part of jsonValue has been processed inside for each mediator.

To remove the slashes, you can directly call the scrip mediator. Or if you want to remove slashes of each object under your for each mediator, your current code is correct, but it won’t process all the messages at once.

As an alternate, you can use aggregate mediator to merge all the split messages into one payload.

Edit #1:

Try this code, which removes the slashes.

```
<foreach id="foreach_id" expression="//jsonValue">
   <sequence>
      <property name="jsonString" expression="json-eval($)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <script language="js">var log = mc.getServiceLog();
       var payload = mc.getProperty('jsonString').toString();
       log.info("script payload::::" + payload); 
       var payloadRemoveSlash = payload.replace('\\', '').replace('"{','{').replace('}"','}'); 
       mc.setProperty('payloadRemoveSlash',payloadRemoveSlash.toString());
       </script>
       <log>
         <property name=":: Body Inside payloadRemoveSlash::" expression="$ctx:payloadRemoveSlash"/>
      </log>
   </sequence>
</foreach>
```

Now, you can convert this property as a Body using enrich mediator and then call endpoint you want. Provided, you use Iterate Mediator instead of For Each mediator.

Comment: Hi @Prabhakaran,
Thanks for your suggestion. aggregated response by using aggregate mediator is "RequestPayload" in my question. and goal is not only removing slash, after removing slash, i need to trace each and every json elemnt values to DB.

Comment: Hi @Justin, Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? What do you mean by tracing each and every JSON elements to DB?

Comment: Hi @Praba,
Inserting lead primary details like Email,Firstname,Lastname,MobilePhone,errorCode etc to Database table.

Comment: Hi @justin, In that case, you have to use iterate and extract each item and insert them individually. PS - Iterate will have only one item inside the flow, but it will iterate for all the occurrences of the messages under the iterate expression you give. Documentation link - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Iterate+Mediator

Comment: Hi @Praba,
 Iterator didn't iterate for all the occurrences of the messages under the iterate expression. it will keep on iterate same element 3 times. Updated Proxy Code also. Can u pls tell me y iteration not happened for each json element?